# 2006 Honda Accord Itermittent Electrical Shut Down Issue

Tags: honda, electrical, accord, intermittent-problems

Electrical Gremlins !!! - I have had on & off issues for 9 months now-  first signs are car won’t lock with key (have replaced batteries) then while driving the audio will shut down briefly & turn it self back on.  Warning and engine lights will come & go, all levers will dip down & pop back up.  2 electricians can’t find the issue- mechanic has replaced battery- cable & leads.  Before mechanic replaced battery the car did die completely 4 times- popped the bonnet & wiggled leads & it started 4 times but after battery replaced still had issues - help my car not ready for heaven yet

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Usually when I see issues like this it can be traced back to bad grounds (earths). Obviously it's something in the wiring, since wiggling the wires up front has some effect on behavior. There are many different grounds throughout the engine compartment. Any one of them could be the culprit. My suggestion is to track any wire which is directly attached between the engine block and/or the body of the car. Check them for corrosion and connection. Good place to start your diagnostic, anyway.